# Telerik Controls are not loading . what am i missing?

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik

i have an application that was given to my by someone else and it's using telerik controls.

the application is originally written in VS2010 framework 4.

when i try to open it on my end, i keep getting errors saying "failed to create designed "Error Creating Control - RadScriptManager1Failed to create designer 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptManager, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.1.519.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4'"

the telerik.web.ui.dll file is in my "bin" folder.

am i missing something? as far as i understand these controls are not free. do i need to buy them to be able to modify this application code and controls? or is there a work around?

Comment: What is the _complete_ text of the error?

Comment: @SLaks Error Creating Control - RadScriptManager1Failed to create designer 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadScriptManager, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.1.519.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4'

Comment: What's the InnerException? (You may need to attach a debugger to VS to find out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need a license to use them. Telerik license their controls to named developers. There is also the issue that you need to run the installer to register the various controls and vsix files correctly.

You can download a trial from Telerik direct, but it is only the latest version, not the one you have.

You can look in the extension manager under online for telerik as well. I had to do that to fix a problem with their installation by downloading the version of their extension from there.

Edit: On the license, if you inherited the code from a developer that left your company, Telerik should be able to move their license to you. Also, the trial you can download doesn't strictly expire, but it does give you warning dialogs, so not suitable for real use. Would get you going though just to prove the project compiles.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're missing `Telerik.Web.Design.dll`.

Comment: Nice one! [Telerik Web Design Assembly](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-vsx-telerik-web-design-assembly.html)

Answer (score 2):

A quote from Telerik's official FAQ:

> **How do Telerik Developer Licenses work?**
>
> Each Developer License allows 1 developer to work with the design-time product. If you purchase a license for a product bundle, such as DevCraft Complete, all the tools in the bundle are licensed to 1 developer, and only that developer is able to develop products with the tools in the bundle. Developer Licenses are perpetual and have **NO deployment limitations** - they allow the use of our controls for an unlimited number of applications spanning various servers and domains. In contrast to competitive products, the Telerik Developer License works **WITHOUT license keys** and you can be certain that you will never get a license key error.

> **Which license should I purchase if I want access to Source code?**
>
> Every Developer License comes with **access to source code for all UI product(s)** (ASP.NET AJAX, WPF, KendoUI Complete for MVC, etc.) included in the product or bundle for the duration of the support term you chose when you purchased or renewed your license. Trial Licenses and free downloads do not come with access to source code.

> **Do you offer a free trial?**
>
> We offer fully functional trials which work without license keys and can be conveniently deployed on any development, test or production machine. The only difference between the trial and the developer build is that with the evaluation copy you will get a trial message on top of the control once in a while when the control is rendered. **Upon replacing the trial dll with the developer dll, the trial message will disappear.**

Link: http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/devcraft.aspx

Legally one license gives the right to one developer to use Telerik's controls. But developer dlls are without any license keys or limitations. As a developer you even get the full source code. But you should read the FAQ regarding the redistribution rights (follow the link above).