# Telerik.web.ui design error?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have following error in visual studio 2010 , asp.net in design mode of page  , c#

> Failed to create designer 'Telerik.web.ui.RadTextBox' ,
>   Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.2.712.35, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=121FAE78165BA3D4

can anyone help me solve it ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Telerik Controls are not loading . what am i missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305664/telerik-controls-are-not-loading-what-am-i-missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading to the [latest `Telerik` version](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/whats-new/release-history/q2-2012-beta-version-2012-2-522.aspx).